# Iterating through 2 maps preserving order on same line output

Tags: algorithm, go, maps

I'm looking to iterate through 2 different maps, and have them output on a side by side basis like

`foo --------- bar zoo--------- car`

The problem stems from not being able to properly use 2 maps, although I dont have to use maps. the order of index doesnt matter but the key pair values must stay the same, so in this instance, zoo must be with car, but doesnt neccessarily have to be NEXT to foo bar,

```
for k, z := range teamA {
                    fmt.Fprintln(w, k+" \t "+z)

                }
for k, z := range teamB {
                    fmt.Fprintln(w, k+" \t "+z)

                }
```

But the error with this approach is it prints out all lines (each map has 5 values, so 10 lines total) in a block format like below, not side by side as i wish. How can I get it to print side by side? not like the block below

```
foo --- bar
zoo ------------ car
```

Comment: Maps are unordered. You need to use a different data structure.

Comment: They key value pairs do not mix orders in maps. @JimB

Comment: The iteration order for key+values is unspecified for maps, and random in the implementation. You specifically asked about "preserving order", which you can't do with a map.

Answer (score 1):

Preload keys from `TeamB` to an array. Then use a simple counter inside the range loop of `TeamA` to retrieve a key from an array and a corresponding value from `TeamB`

```
keys := make([]string, len(teamA))
i := 0
for k := range teamA {
                    keys[i] = k
                    i++
                }
i = 0
for k, z := range teamB {
                    kA := keys[i]
                    vA := teamA[k]
                    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v\t%v\t%v\t%v", k, z, kA, vA)
                    i++
                }
```

See https://play.golang.org/p/18Im2T3ZpCL
If the sizes of maps are different, don`t forget to account for that.